# if I add SSO for both facebook and Gmail then should I treat users who login from both with same email id as new user?

Tags: ios, facebook, single-sign-on

I have created facebook sso  and it works perfect.I am getting the email id as one of the unique factor in my server db .So it treats the user who has logged in the first time as new user and after submitting the form with extra info as already existing user.

I was thinking of adding gmail sso but my query is if the user in gmail with the same email id as the one he used to enter facebook account is already existing then should I treat him as existing user or new user as the email id is unique and already exists in the server db.

Or remove email id as the unique factor in the above case or just check if the user is signing in from facebook/gmail and then do the further verifications ? Please help me out with this .

Any help or link for the above query would help me a great deal.I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say just allow the email to be the unique id. If user uses the same email for both accounts so be it. Many users of all social medias use one email to connect to all of their accounts.

Comment: So if the user has already registered his account via facebook and tried to sign in via Gmail next time .I should let him through ?

Comment: If he uses the same email account yes. Why not. After all his email is already creating an entry in db. Otherwise you are going to have the same user creating two different accounts one with each social media and it is going to be save consuming and redundant. That's just not a good business practice in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your time I have another addon query : Since he is using Gmail to sign in He can post messages on the wall but if he uses gmail then I dont know how I can allow him to do that (even posting an event). If he using Gmail service should I again asking him to auth facebook signin so that I can get session.id or id there any backend code/library for gmail to hand the wall post directly to facebook even if he has logged in via gmail? Thank you Sir for your time I really appreciate it .Please help me out.

Comment: Facebook----> Wall fine                                                   Gmail ----> Wall (Should he auth facebook for that ?)

Comment: I would imagine that it should be so. Since he is using the same email address for both accounts it should be allowed. Why not connect both api's in your app so users can link their accounts once and can post on both media at once? That is a good idea since it will entice more users to join.

Comment: How do I link their accounts Sir ? That would be great if there is any service or step by step procedure.I am a bit new to integrating API and services.So logging onto one would be like logging into both facebook/Gmail ? That would be Awesome .Please guide me Sir.

Comment: What I was saying is linking both accounts is a good idea. I believe it can be done with a if statement or switch. But I haven't done it myself. I'm sure there tons of materials out there to guide you. You just have to research it yourself my friend. That's how build my work.

Comment: Thank you sir .Please let me know if you come across any material will help me a great deal.